# How to get the body of an email?

Tags: testing, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am new to testing using cucumber with capybara. I got an application to test whose flow is:'after submitting a form, an email will be sent to the user which contains the link to another app. In order to access the app we have to open the mail and click the link, which will redirect to the app.'. I don't have access to the mail Id. Is there any way to extract that link and continue with the flow? I have tried something but is not working. Below is the snippet I was trying:

```
path_regex = /(?:"https?\:\/\/.*?)(\/.*?)(?:")/
email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
path = email.body.match(path_regex)[1]
visit(path)
```

Its showing 'unknown error:'URL' must be a string' error.
can some one help me with it?

Comment: Capybara is Ruby. So look for Ruby libraries that allow you to interact with email & SMTP servers.

Comment: tried but unsuccessful..If you can give me the name of any specific gem, it might help..

Answer (score 0):

I use MailCatcher works exactly how you're describing.

Comment: can you tell me little in details?

Comment: mailcatcher doesn't support some of the gems..I am unable to get the configuration part..Can  u have help me to configure it?whats are the exacts steps?